# Random walk on the integer - computing the "steps" in R

Tags: r

Starts at 0 and at each step moves 1 or -1 with equal probability. To illustrate this walk, consider the following: a marker is placed at zero on the number line, and a fair coin is flipped. If the coin lands on heads, the marker is moved one unit to the right. If it lands on tails, the marker is moved one unit to the left.Basically, I know how to simulate a random walk but instead of having the position x for each n;

```
function(n){

return(cumsum(c(0, sample(c(-1, 1), size = n-1, replace =TRUE))))

}
```

I want to get a vector with each modification (either 1 or -1)but I don't really know how to modify my current function. Maybe with another variable counting the difference between each position?)

Comment: You could perhaps use the `diff()` function.

Comment: [Here](https://www.stat.auckland.ac.nz/~ihaka/downloads/Taupo-handouts.pdf) are some slides on vectorization in R (using a random walk) as an example.

Comment: Not sure if I understand, but I think the vector with the modifications is already in your function:  `sample(c(-1, 1), size = n-1, replace =TRUE)`